# Converting .xyz file coordinates to LibSVM format?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I've run into a bit of a delima. I've been doing some 3D scanning and would like to convert .xyz file attained from the scanning process to LibSVM format.

the .xyz file would look like this:

```
31 423 578
34 423 582
42 423 621
43 423 650
47 423 668
48 423 677
80 423 670
84 423 589
86 423 602
88 404 553
89 403 583
89 404 664
90 393 673
90 396 563
90 397 607
90 403 624
90 404 666
91 409 517
91 411 579
```

And LibSVM format is like this:

```
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ...
```

What is to be considered before going about this process? What exactly would my label and index value(s) be? I'm sure value1 would equal the x coordinate. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

Any demonstration code to give me a gist of the process would certain be appreciated. But words are great.

Comment: and what is the problem you are trying to model, you want to classify **each point**? To what?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @rzo 3D scan something, do some classification with LibSVM, and possible be able to view the 3D scan again. I'd like to be able to classify something from everything else. For example, I had a piece of chewing gum on a flat surface. I'd like to ONLY recognize the chewing gum somehow. If that makes sense.